# How to use IN contains ignore case in QuerydslPredicateExecutor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, querydsl

What I trying to achieve is using `IN` query which is ignore uppercase or lower case in my `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`, but I can't find the function and any docs about it. Here is what I do:

```
List<String> statusList = new ArrayList<String>();
statusList.add("ASSIGNED");
statusList.add("Got Permit");

QTransStuffing qTransStuffing = QTransStuffing.transStuffing;
BooleanExpression isCanceledFalse = qTransStuffing.cancelStuffing.eq(false);
BooleanExpression eStatusList = qTransStuffing.status.in(statusList);
Predicate predicate = isCanceledFalse.and(eStatusList);

transStuffingRepository.findAll(predicate)
```

As you can see, if we do query `qTransStuffing.status.in(statusList)` this won't ignore case, how can I achieve IN query with ignore case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a better way than:

```
List<String> statusList = new ArrayList<String>();
statusList.add("ASSIGNED");
statusList.add("GOT PERMIT");

QTransStuffing qTransStuffing = QTransStuffing.transStuffing;
BooleanExpression isCanceledFalse = qTransStuffing.cancelStuffing.eq(false);
BooleanExpression eStatusList = qTransStuffing.status.upperCase().in(statusList);
Predicate predicate = isCanceledFalse.and(eStatusList);

transStuffingRepository.findAll(predicate)
```